# How do I create a horizontal scroll view with unlimited pages?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to make an app that you can scroll through and it displays a different string on each page. I though I should use scroll views as they seem to be how I can do this. An example of what I want is UberFacts app. This app you can scroll along and it has a different fact each time. This is obviously not just thousands of different view controllers that are linked by the page control. How do I make view controllers work like UberFacts?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/).

Answer (score 0):

UberFacts seem to use a paginated ScrollView and each page looks like a vertical ScrollView also (you can see by the bounce). But is just one ViewController that manage all those pages.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials that teach exactly this? Most I've found just give weird examples and I can't seem to use them examples in a way like uberfacts has used them...

Comment: In swift i found nothing, but this article from Ray Wenderlich
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content
may help you. It does much more than you need, like zoom images, but the main idea of the pages is here also